# Slow SQL Sync with Microsoft Sync Framework on Mobile Client

Tags: windows-mobile, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

we are developing an application which uses MS Sync Framework to sync data between Windows CE 6.0 with SQL CE 3.5 SP1 Clients and an SQL 2008 Database. Our major problem is a slow sync time up to 1 minute for 15 tables which are totally empty.
Here's a break down of our components:

Server:

- Sql Server 2008
- 15 tables with activated change tracking
- WCF Service with endpoint for the mobile sync (uses Sync Framework 2.0)

Client (Mobile)

- Windows CE 6.0
- NET Application using Sync Framework for Devices (CTP 1) which starts the sync

As I mentioned above, the sync takes up to 1 minute without any changes and empty tables. The mobile device is in its dock.
This is a deal breaker for a production environment. Does anybody have any experience in this field? Is there a way to improve things?
Thanks for any responses.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
The sync time improves dramatically if you change the batch size.I trid the following hot fix.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973058
I did'nt see any improvements.

Comment: In fact, when we installed this hotfix, it destroyed our Visual Studio 2008 installation. We couldn't open mobile devices projects anymore. We could reproduce this behaviour after a re-install.